# How can i optimize my sudoku generator code to generate sudoku puzzles faster

Tags: python, optimization, backtracking, sudoku

I modified the sudoku generator code I found at https://medium.com/codex/building-a-sudoku-solver-and-generator-in-python-1-3-f29d3ede6b23 to look like this:

```
def generateBoard():
    print("Generating puzzle...please wait")
    time.sleep(1)
    gameboard = createEmpty() # creates a list with the three diagonal boxes filled and the rest filled with zeros
    gameboard = solve(gameboard) # changes the unsolved board DIRECTLY to a solved board
    gameboard = removeNumbers(gameboard,38)
    print("\nHere's your puzzle :)")
    printBoard(gameboard)
```

So what the above code does is, it first creates a list in which the three 3x3 subgrids in the leading diagonal are filled with numbers 1 through 9 (sudoku rules) using the `createEmpty()` function below:

```
def createEmpty():
    board = [[0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]
    for i in range(3):
        box = shuffle(range(1,10))
        for y in range(i*3, i*3+3):
            for x in range(i*3, i*3+3):
                board[y][x] = box.pop()
    return board
```

This function was only returning a 9x9 list filled with zeros (first line) before, but according to the article i read in that website, it said that using this method of filling the three boxes in the diagonal with numbers before solving would save some time in backtracking so i changed it and it affected the time spent but by only a little amount.

```
def solve(board):
    empty = find_empty(board)
    
    if not empty:
        return True
    col, row = empty
    for num in shuffle(range(1,10)):
        if valid(board, num, empty):
            board[row][col] = num
        
            if solve(board):
                return board
                
            board[row][col] = 0
                
    return False
```

So after creating the list, it uses the `solve()` function above which uses backtracking to solve the partially filled board.
So after getting a solved sudoku board, i created a function (`removeNumbers`) to remove numbers from the board to create the puzzle. The function and its dependent functions are below:

```
def removeNumbers(solvedboard,hints=None):
    board = copy.deepcopy(solvedboard)
    remaining = 81
    if not hints: hints = random.randrange(28, 40)
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            boxCoords = [(i,j) for j in range(y*3, (y*3)+3) for i in range(x*3, (x*3)+3)]
            for n in range(random.choice(range(1,5))):
                a, b = random.choice(boxCoords)
                board[b][a] = 0
                boxCoords.remove((a,b))
                remaining -= 1
                
    coords = [(i,j) for i in range(9) for j in range(9)]
    coords = list(filter(lambda p: board[p[0]][p[1]] != 0, coords))
    random.shuffle(coords)
    
    for row, col in coords:
        
        if remaining == hints:
            break
            
        num = board[row][col]
        board[row][col] = 0
        
        n = numberOfSolutions(board, solvedboard)
        
        if n != 1:
            board[row][col] = num
            continue
                
        remaining -= 1
        #printBoard(board)
        #print(remaining, hints)
        
    return board

def numberOfSolutions(board, solved=[], ret=False):
    solutions = []
    # find a solution in which an empty square has a valid value and add it to the list(solutions)
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if board[row][col] == 0:
                dupeBoard = copy.deepcopy(board)
                solution = getSolution(dupeBoard, row, col)
                if not ret and solution != solved:
                    return 0
                if solution:
                    solutions.append(code(solution))
    solutions = list(set(solutions))

    return len(solutions) if not ret else solutions

def getSolution(board, row, col):
    for n in range(1, 10):
        # insert a valid number into the (row,col) and return a solved board or if there are no solutions for that board, return False
        if valid(board, n, (col, row)):
            board[row][col] = n
            
            if (solvedboard:=solve(board)):
                return solvedboard
            
            board[row][col] = 0     
    return False

def valid(board, num, pos):
    x, y = pos
    # check rows
    if board[y].count(num) > 0:
        return False
    # check columns
    if [board[j][x] for j in range(9)].count(num) > 0:
        return False
    # 3x3 grid
    grid_x, grid_y = x-(x % 3), y-(y % 3)
    grid = [board[j][i] for j in range(grid_y, grid_y+3) for i in range(grid_x, grid_x+3)]
    if grid.count(num) > 0:
        return False
    return True
```

The `removeNumbers()` function has a local variable `hints` which represents the number of clues present in the sudoku puzzle and which contains a random number from 28 to 40, with 28 being the hardest and 39 being the simplest.
After removing the numbers from the board, the resulting board is printed out using the `printBoard()` function below:

```
def printBoard(board):
    print("-"*41)
    for y in range(len(board)):
        if y % 3 == 0:
            print(('||'+'-'*11)*3, end='')
            print('||')
        print(f"|| {board[y][0] if board[y][0]!=0 else ' '} | {board[y][1] if board[y][1]!=0 else ' '} | {board[y][2] if board[y][2]!=0 else ' '} ||", end='')
        print(f" {board[y][3] if board[y][3]!=0 else ' '} | {board[y][4] if board[y][4]!=0 else ' '} | {board[y][5] if board[y][5]!=0 else ' '} ||", end='')
        print(f" {board[y][6] if board[y][6]!=0 else ' '} | {board[y][7] if board[y][7]!=0 else ' '} | {board[y][8] if board[y][8]!=0 else ' '} ||")
    print(('||'+'-'*11)*3, end='')
    print('||')
    print('-'*41)
```

Right now my generator generates simple sudoku puzzles in 30+ seconds and hard sudoku puzzles in 3+ minutes. And the code in that website generates simple in 0.22 secs, medium in 2+ secs and hard in 20+ secs.
But after several debugging, I found out that a large amount of time is spent at the `removeNumbers()` function. Having said all of that, I'll appreciate it if you could help me to optimize the `removeNumbers()` function and therefore reduce the amount of time spent generating the sudoku puzzle.

Comment: You'd better use a profiler

Comment: Did you write the `removeNumbers()` code or is that mostly part of the original code provided by someone else?

Comment: @Mast, Yes i wrote the code all by myself

Comment: Except for the ```numberOfSolutions``` function, which i got from the website i mentioned in the post. And i didn't copy it, i modified it because the website's was a bit long

Comment: Why did you ask?

Comment: Why do i need a profiler @El?